# An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.7), and Bundler cannot continue Cannot create rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, sqlite

I am absolutely new to ruby on rails. 
I am having ruby 1.9.3p194 and Rails 3.2.8 installed on my Ubuntu 13.04.
I tried to create my first using the code

```
rails new rotten --T
```

I got something like this

```
      create  
      create  README.rdoc
      create  Rakefile
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
      create  app
      create  app/assets/images/rails.png
      create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/mailers
      create  app/models
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/mailers/.gitkeep
      create  app/models/.gitkeep
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
      create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
      create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  db
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  doc
      create  doc/README_FOR_APP
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/.gitkeep
      create  lib/assets
      create  lib/assets/.gitkeep
      create  log
      create  log/.gitkeep
      create  public
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/index.html
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  script
      create  script/rails
      create  test/fixtures
      create  test/fixtures/.gitkeep
      create  test/functional
      create  test/functional/.gitkeep
      create  test/integration
      create  test/integration/.gitkeep
      create  test/unit
      create  test/unit/.gitkeep
      create  test/performance/browsing_test.rb
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.gitkeep
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.gitkeep
      create  vendor/plugins
      create  vendor/plugins/.gitkeep
         run  bundle install
Enter your password to install the bundled RubyGems to your system: 
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake (10.1.0) 
Using i18n (0.6.4) 
Using multi_json (1.7.7) 
Using activesupport (3.2.8) 
Using builder (3.0.4) 
Using activemodel (3.2.8) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using journey (1.0.4) 
Using rack (1.4.5) 
Using rack-cache (1.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.2) 
Using hike (1.2.3) 
Using tilt (1.4.1) 
Using sprockets (2.1.3) 
Using actionpack (3.2.8) 
Using mime-types (1.23) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.14) 
Using mail (2.4.4) 
Using actionmailer (3.2.8) 
Using arel (3.0.2) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.37) 
Using activerecord (3.2.8) 
Using activeresource (3.2.8) 
Using bundler (1.3.5) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.6.3) 
Using execjs (1.4.0) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using rack-ssl (1.3.3) 
Using json (1.8.0) 
Using rdoc (3.12.2) 
Using thor (0.18.1) 
Using railties (3.2.8) 
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2) 
Using jquery-rails (3.0.4) 
Using rails (3.2.8) 
Using sass (3.2.9) 
Using sass-rails (3.2.6) 
Installing sqlite3 (1.3.7) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb 
checking for sqlite3.h... no
sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
    --with-sqlite3-dir
    --without-sqlite3-dir
    --with-sqlite3-include
    --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
    --with-sqlite3-lib
    --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
    --enable-local
    --disable-local


Gem files will remain installed in /home/dvs/.bundler/tmp/3341/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/dvs/.bundler/tmp/3341/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.7'` succeeds before bundling.
```

and I tried

```
sudo gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.7'
```

Now I got an error like this

```
dvs@dvs-Inspiron-N4010:~/testruby$ sudo gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.7'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... no
sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
    --with-sqlite3-dir
    --without-sqlite3-dir
    --with-sqlite3-include
    --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
    --with-sqlite3-lib
    --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
    --enable-local
    --disable-local


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
```

Kindly Help Me
Thank You

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It's failing because you are missing a dependency. You can get it by running
`sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev`

Comment: Yup.Now the app created sucessfully. But while running the server<pre>rails s</pre>it shows another error

Comment: Is your app is running?

Comment: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:51:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)

Comment: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
 from script/rails:6:in `require'
 from script/rails:6:in `<main>'

Comment: Ok install nodejs javascript runtime is not installed. then do bundle install

Comment: Yes..Done. I did $sudo apt-get install nodejs and then $ bundle update. Now all working fine. Thank You

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue using Fedora. For posterity and the Yum folks...

```
sudo yum install libsq3-devel
```

Answer (score 1):

This fixes it for Amazon Linux (AWS)

```
sudo yum install sqlite-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

run `$sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev`

if it responds:

> E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure
>   -a' to correct the problem.

then run  `$sudo dpkg --configure -a`
run `$rails s`

if it responds:

> Downloading nokogiri-1.10.0 revealed dependencies not in the API or
>   the lockfile (mini_portile2 (~> 2.4.0)).

Either installing with `--full-index` or running `bundle update nokogiri` should fix the problem.
run `$ bundle update nokogiri`
and all will be perfect again!

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow! I suggest you to format you answer better to make it easier to read and understand.

Comment: You can format the programm code in your question better with the grave accent character `code` or tripple ```, for multi-line code blocks